# jest ( with tsjest) + typescript outDir not working as expected

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a gatsby project that I am using with tsjest and typescript. During the testing, I am getting the error...

```
error TS5055: Cannot write file '/Users/Jeff/go/src/site/frontend/node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/gatsby-browser-entry.js' because it would overwrite input file.
```

which seems straightforward enough, but when I try to setup my tsconfig to use `outDir` as the link suggests, I still get the error. The only way I can get it to work is if I set `noEmit: true`....

My config is below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNEXT",                       
    "module": "ESNext",                  
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],                        
    "allowJs": true,               
    "jsx": "react",               
    "outDir": "./dist/",                   
    "rootDir": "./",                  
    "strict": true,                 
    "noUnusedLocals": true,              
    "noUnusedParameters": true,            
    "noImplicitReturns": true,          
    "moduleResolution": "node",         
    "esModuleInterop": true              
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./node_modules/gatsby/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules"]
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts',
  verbose: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    'typeface-roboto|\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js'
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/.cache'], // ignore gatsby cache tests
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      enableTsDiagnostics: true
    }
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  // the 'undoes' ignore of node modules to transpile defaults in gatsby to es5 which is needed in anything that imports something from gatsby
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!gatsby)'],
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node']
};
```